# Rubyで簡潔にeachなどの機能を持つクラスを実装する方法

Tags: ruby

例えば、フィボナッチ数列`(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946 ..)`を作るようなクラスを作りたいとして、下のようなコードを書いたとします。

```
 class Fibonacci
   def initialize(n)
     @n = n
     @f1 = 1
     @f0 = 0
   end

   def to_a
     (0..(@n-1)).map {|t| fib t }
   end

   def fib t
     case t
     when 0..1
       t
     else
       now = @f1 + @f0
       @f0 = @f1
       @f1 = now
     end
   end
   private :fib
 end
```

このとき、このコードは下のように実行することができるかと思われます。

```
 Fibonacci.new(10).to_a.each_with_index do |result, index|
   puts "#{index + 1}番目: #{result}"
 end
```

とはいえ、わざわざ`to_a`を呼び出して、一度`Array`にしてから、`each_with_index`を呼び出すのは非常に冗長のように感じます。むしろこのオブジェクトに対して、直接`each_with_index`(あるいは`each`)を呼び出せたほうが簡潔になるように感じます。例えば下のようにです。

```
 Fibonacci.new(10).each_with_index do |result, index|
   puts "#{index + 1}番目: #{result}"
 end
```

このようにするためには、このクラスにはどのようなコードを追加してあげればいいのでしょうか。同様に、`map`なども共通で実装できれば、よりベターです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Enumerable` を `include` して `each` を実装すればよいです。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/Enumerable.html

> 要約
>
> 繰り返しを行なうクラスのための Mix-in。このモジュールの メソッドは全て each を用いて定義されているので、インクルード するクラスには each が定義されていなければなりません。

実装のポイントは

- `Enumerable` を `include` する
- `Enumerable` に必要な `each` を実装する

ロジックのポイントは、列挙するという特質から

- `yield` を使うと `each` をうまく実装できることが多い
- メモ化するとリソースがうまく節約できることが多い

その上で複数回の `each` の呼び出しなどを考慮すると以下のようなコードが妥当そうです。

```
require 'enumerator'

class Fibonacci
  include Enumerable

  def initialize(n)
    @n = n
    @fib = {1 => 0, 2 => 1}
  end

  def each
    1.upto @n do |i|
      yield fib i
    end
  end

  private
  def fib(n)
    return @fib[n] if @fib[n]
    @fib[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
  end
end


if __FILE__ == $0 then
  f = Fibonacci.new 10
  f.each_with_index do |n, i|
    puts "#{i + 1}: #{n}"
  end
  puts f.map {|x| x + 10}
end
```

`Enumerable` を `include` して `each` を定義していれば、 `map` などのほか `include?` なども使えるようになります。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/Enumerable.html

> インスタンスメソッド
>
> all? any? chunk collect map collect_concat flat_map count cycle detect find drop drop_while each_cons each_entry each_slice each_with_index each_with_object entries to_a find_all select find_index first grep group_by include? member? inject reduce lazy max max_by min min_by minmax minmax_by none? one? partition reject reverse_each slice_before sort sort_by take take_while to_h zip

Answer (score 7):

Enumerableをincludeして、eachメソッドを実装すれば可能です。

実装部分は手抜きですが、例えば以下の様にすれば `to_a`無しで `each_with_index` を呼び出すことができるようになります。

```
require 'enumerator'

class Fibonacci
  include Enumerable
  def initialize(n)
    @n = n
    @f1 = 1
    @f0 = 0
  end

  def to_a
    (0..(@n-1)).map {|t| fib t }
  end

  # 追加
  def each
    to_a.each do |x|
      yield x
    end
  end

  def fib t
    case t
      when 0..1
        t
      else
        now = @f1 + @f0
        @f0 = @f1
        @f1 = now
    end
  end
  private :fib

end
```

このeachの実装は簡単のために`to_a`の呼び出しをクラス側で肩代わりしているだけです。
これによって、以下の様に呼び出すことができます。

```
Fibonacci.new(10).each_with_index do |result, index|
   puts "#{index + 1}番目: #{result}"
end
```

map も可能です。

```
puts Fibonacci.new(10).map {|x| x + 10}
```

Answer (score 4):

私なら以下のような `Enumerator` を使った実装にします。

```ruby
def fib
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    x, y = 1, 1
    loop do
      yielder.yield x
      tmp = x + y
      x = y
      y = tmp
    end
  end.lazy
end

fib.each do |n|
  puts n
end
```

いわゆるジェネレータ的な実装だと思います。
遅延評価なので、無限リストとして扱えます。

個人的には UNIX ツールを作るのに便利なので良く使います。

https://github.com/fukayatsu/json2yaml/blob/master/lib/json2yaml.rb

Comment: Enumerator の公式ドキュメントにちょうどフィボナッチ数列を求める例が載っていました。

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.1.0/class/Enumerator.html#S_NEW

やっていることはだいたい同じですが、こちらの方が完結に記述されています。